# Clarification required related to for loop in java code

Tags: java

I have the below function which inserts empty list in db even though there is an error in order status validation. I suspect it due to the for loop is called more than one time after user clicked the submit button in the screen but unable to find any trace for multiple call to the function,

```
for (int i=0; i<unassigned.getCount(); i++){
        refund = unassigned.getRefund(i);
        orderRefNum = refund.getOrderRefNum();              

        if (refund.getStatus()==Order.NOT_PRINTED){     
            boolean result = updateRefundList();            
            colOfRefunds.add(refund);
            updateNewOrAmended(refund);
        } else {
            log.info("Error in validating Order");
        }
    }

       if (colOfRefunds.size()>0){              
        updateRefundListTable();
        if (listNumbersCount>0){
            listNumbersString += "|";
        }
        listNumbersString += refundListRefNum;
        listNumbersCount++;
    }
```

Now i moved the condition which inserts empty result set inside the for loop like below and not sure how it will work in my live environment since i do not have any local or non prod environment to test the logic,

```
for (int i=0; i<unassigned.getCount(); i++){
        refund = unassigned.getRefund(i);
        orderRefNum = refund.getOrderRefNum();              

        if (refund.getStatus()==Order.NOT_PRINTED){     
            boolean result = updateRefundList();            
            colOfRefunds.add(refund);
            updateNewOrAmended(refund);

        if (colOfRefunds.size()>0){             
        updateRefundListTable();
        if (listNumbersCount>0){
            listNumbersString += "|";
        }
        listNumbersString += refundListRefNum;
        listNumbersCount++;
    }
        } else {
            log.info("Error in validating Order");
        }
    }
```

So just wanted a clarification whether the above changes will cause any issues in the list creation or will works as expected like previous logic.

Comment: Why don't you test it out in your JVM?

Comment: I think the first thing you need to do is double-check your indentation and punctuation, since that first block won't even compile and neither is indented in a way that makes sense.